# Rounding numbers with 2 decimals

Tags: java, format, rounding

Please don't report this question as 'already posted or reported' which is NOT the case, it might/should be but it's NOT. This is a extremely strange performance of JAVA. I also wonder a bit if the one who was responsible for digit-handling is still working for JAVA, cause he/she made a Mess of it!! A jungle of codes and formatting.
Anyway here my ghostly problem. (it's a part of the code but only the relevant part)
As you can see all variables (a,b,c and d) are `double`. But it systematically results in `Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String`
Whatever I changed, tried and look about on the internet it keeps on refusing to work. But down below, an example found on Internet does work. But it's exactly the same!! Both variables are declared as `double`and both converted via the same method!!

```java
case 2:

         Hypotheek hypspa = new HypSpaar(UitvoerHypotheek.hs,UitvoerHypotheek.lt,UitvoerHypotheek.perc);
         double a =  hypspa.aflossing();
         double b =  hypspa.aflossing();
         double c =  hypspa.rente();
         double d =  (1+((float)UitvoerHypotheek.perc/100));

         System.out.println("jaar" +   "    inleg " + "           gespaard " + "       rente " );

         for (int t=1; t<=UitvoerHypotheek.lt; t++)
         {

         System.out.format(  "      "     +  "%.2f", b  + "        " + "%.2f", a  + "     " + "%.2f", c + "     \n");

         a =  d*(a) + b;

        }
```

```
java

public class test8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num = 1.34567;
        System.out.format("%.4f", num);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying for insert multiple doubles into a string, you mean something like this:

```
System.out.format("      %.2f        %.2f     %.2f     \n", b, a, c);
```

What you had is passing strings as the arguments to format, and you can't use `%f` to insert a string argument.

```
System.out.format("      " + "%.2f", b + "        " + "%.2f", a + "     " + "%.2f", c + "     \n");
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                   format string          string arg 1           string arg 2       string arg 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
      double num = 1.34567;
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
     df.format(num);
```